# Using SketchFlow to prototype MS Surface Applications

Tags: wpf, prototyping, sketchflow, pixelsense

We're doing mockups/prototyping on a MS Surface device and I wonder if anyone has succeeded in using [SketchFlow](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/SketchFlow_OverView.aspx) for this. The problem that I see is that the code generated by the tool uses normal WPF controls (Button, etc.) instead of the contact aware surface counterparts (SurfaceButton) which means that they won't work nice on the surface unless you also use a mouse.

Additionally, it would be nice if it was possible to hook in to other gesture events to trigger sketchflow transitions. Like the pinch gestures to switch page etc.

Has anyone had any success with prototyping for Surface using Sketchflow. If so, how did you do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a trigger or behavior that would handle the other gesture events you mention to navigate around the SketchFlow player that would be re-usable, and should enable what you are suggesting.

As for the controls, I am not very familiar with surface development, but you might also be able to create a behavior that when attached adds some sort of surface ability, like clickability to the visual object.

Happy to help if I can be of any assistance.